# AWS Connect API - Creating contact flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-connect

I am trying to create a contact flow in my connect instance and keep getting the following issue when trying to use the aws cli.

```
An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the CreateContactFlow operation: Invalid request
```

Here is the command im trying to run

```
aws connect create-contact-flow --instance-id 1d27d5a7-9101-4314-9bad-ad6b0df45d02 --type CONTACT_FLOW --name uki_dtc_test --content "{`"Version`":`"2019-10-30`",`"StartAction`":`"a2243fda-4f0d-4519-9cc7-c4b56f67a8c0`",`"Metadata`":{`"entryPointPosition`":{`"x`":20,`"y`":20},`"snapToGrid`":false,`"ActionMetadata`":{`"daa98067-59f9-4a7b-b628-df4fab712f4e`":{`"position`":{`"x`":802,`"y`":5},`"useDynamic`":false,`"ContactFlow`":{`"id`":`"arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:553243264439:instance/1d27d5a7-9101-4314-9bad-ad6b0df45d02/contact-flow/c5a6ed55-bacb-4a50-a45b-6167cf15449f`",`"text`":`"UKIAfterCallSurveyMainMenu`"}},`"d264e0c2-b926-4032-a105-184d7f2cc74b`":{`"position`":{`"x`":581,`"y`":22},`"useDynamic`":false},`"192e2e35-b42a-423b-8aff-90ff20ee2e52`":{`"position`":{`"x`":1029,`"y`":50}},`"a2243fda-4f0d-4519-9cc7-c4b56f67a8c0`":{`"position`":{`"x`":235,`"y`":34},`"useDynamic`":false,`"queue`":{`"id`":`"arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:553243264439:instance/1d27d5a7-9101-4314-9bad-ad6b0df45d02/queue/e46b202b-585e-4468-b406-bb319da83a1f`",`"text`":`"TestSurvey`"}},`"840faec3-893c-4e60-9ab5-460ef5a6e611`":{`"position`":{`"x`":466,`"y`":311}}}},`"Actions`":[{`"Identifier`":`"daa98067-59f9-4a7b-b628-df4fab712f4e`",`"Parameters`":{`"ContactFlowId`":`"arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:553243264439:instance/1d27d5a7-9101-4314-9bad-ad6b0df45d02/contact-flow/c5a6ed55-bacb-4a50-a45b-6167cf15449f`"},`"Transitions`":{`"NextAction`":`"192e2e35-b42a-423b-8aff-90ff20ee2e52`",`"Errors`":[{`"NextAction`":`"192e2e35-b42a-423b-8aff-90ff20ee2e52`",`"ErrorType`":`"NoMatchingError`"}],`"Conditions`":[]},`"Type`":`"TransferToFlow`"},{`"Identifier`":`"d264e0c2-b926-4032-a105-184d7f2cc74b`",`"Transitions`":{`"NextAction`":`"daa98067-59f9-4a7b-b628-df4fab712f4e`",`"Errors`":[{`"NextAction`":`"daa98067-59f9-4a7b-b628-df4fab712f4e`",`"ErrorType`":`"NoMatchingError`"},{`"NextAction`":`"daa98067-59f9-4a7b-b628-df4fab712f4e`",`"ErrorType`":`"QueueAtCapacity`"}],`"Conditions`":[]},`"Type`":`"TransferContactToQueue`"},{`"Identifier`":`"192e2e35-b42a-423b-8aff-90ff20ee2e52`",`"Type`":`"DisconnectParticipant`",`"Parameters`":{},`"Transitions`":{}},{`"Identifier`":`"a2243fda-4f0d-4519-9cc7-c4b56f67a8c0`",`"Parameters`":{`"QueueId`":`"arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:553243264439:instance/1d27d5a7-9101-4314-9bad-ad6b0df45d02/queue/e46b202b-585e-4468-b406-bb319da83a1f`"},`"Transitions`":{`"NextAction`":`"840faec3-893c-4e60-9ab5-460ef5a6e611`",`"Errors`":[{`"NextAction`":`"192e2e35-b42a-423b-8aff-90ff20ee2e52`",`"ErrorType`":`"NoMatchingError`"}],`"Conditions`":[]},`"Type`":`"UpdateContactTargetQueue`"},{`"Identifier`":`"840faec3-893c-4e60-9ab5-460ef5a6e611`",`"Parameters`":{`"FlowLoggingBehavior`":`"Enabled`"},`"Transitions`":{`"NextAction`":`"d264e0c2-b926-4032-a105-184d7f2cc74b`",`"Errors`":[],`"Conditions`":[]},`"Type`":`"UpdateFlowLoggingBehavior`"}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the double quotes within the json string.